# How can I include an image in the title content achieved with \maketitle in the amsart class?

Tags: titles, amsart

I am writing my thesis and using the `amsart` document class. On the first page I have used `\maketitle`, and have specified Title, Author and Abstract in the preamble, so these are produced. I would like to insert an image between the Author and the Abstract. At the moment I have added it after `\maketitle`, but this then follows the abstract, rather than preceding it. Is there a way to resolve this?

Edit to include code - I know there's a lot of packages there that probably aren't relevant, but decided to include everything I'm using just in case!

Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1.5in, right=1in]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.tif}{png}{.png}{`convert #1 `dirname #1`/`basename #1 .tif`.png}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
Abstract text...
\end{abstract}
\maketitle
\begin{center}\includegraphics[width=0.14\textwidth]{logo}\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I redefined the internal `\@maketitle` to include the image. Use the newly defined `\titleimage` command to include your image in the standard way:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\titleimage{\includegraphics[<options>]{<image>}}
```

A complete example

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\titleimage[1]{\gdef\@titleimage{#1}}
\def\@maketitle{%
  \normalfont\normalsize
  \let\@makefnmark\relax  \let\@thefnmark\relax
  \ifx\@empty\@date\else \@footnotetext{\@setdate}\fi
  \ifx\@empty\@subjclass\else \@footnotetext{\@setsubjclass}\fi
  \ifx\@empty\@keywords\else \@footnotetext{\@setkeywords}\fi
  \ifx\@empty\thankses\else \@footnotetext{%
    \def\par{\let\par\@par}\@setthanks}\fi
  \@mkboth{\@nx\shortauthors}{\@nx\shorttitle}%
  \global\topskip42\p@\relax % 5.5pc   "   "   "     "     "
  \@settitle
  \ifx\@empty\authors \else \@setauthors \fi
  \ifx\@empty\@dedicatory
  \else
    \baselineskip18\p@
    \vtop{\centering{\footnotesize\itshape\@dedicatory\@@par}%
      \global\dimen@i\prevdepth}\prevdepth\dimen@i
  \fi
  \vskip10pt\begin{center}
  \@titleimage
  \end{center}
  \@setabstract
  \normalsize
  \if@titlepage
    \newpage
  \else
    \dimen@34\p@ \advance\dimen@-\baselineskip
    \vskip\dimen@\relax
  \fi
} % end \@maketitle
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}
\titleimage{\includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image-a}}
\begin{abstract}
test abstract
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

Test text

\end{document}
```

[image]